# How to get Value of object from list of objects by Using Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

From the below code require to get values based on type from List,

```
List<Type> types= Arrays.asList(new Type("type1","Values1"),new Type("type2","Values2"));

List<AnotherType> anotherTypes = new ArrayList<>();

for (Type type:types){
    AnotherType  anotherType = new AnotherType();
    
    anotherType.settype1Value(?);
    anotherType.settype2Value(?);

    anotherTypes.add(anotherType);
}
```

easy way to find values in the ?.

Comment: `types.stream().map(t->new  AnotherType(...)).collect(toList());`

Comment: Try to clear your question again and add an example input output.

Comment: Do you mean like `anotherType.settype1Value(type.getType());`? What is the expected result? Also, can we assume that you classes have got usual getters and setters? I am sorry, the question is unclear to me, please edit and clarify.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand you question. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow try to provide the classes you are using and try to explain what *exatly* are you trying to achieve.

Having said that, to transform one object into another, using streams, you can use [map()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-maps-streams). Something like that:

```java
List<AnotherType> anotherType = types
    .stream()
    .map(t -> new AnotherType(t.getTypeValue1(), t.getTypeValue2()))
    .collectors(Collectors.toList());
```